# Bootstrap group items don't either hide/collapse

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `Bootstrap's collapse group items` defined as below. If I understood well this should `collapse/expand` out of the box of `bootstrap` nevertheless it doesn't work at all. Should I add something additionally to my java script file or? What am I missing?

**Collapse group items:**

```
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
  
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
                    Test text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
                    Test text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Test text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**The libraries I have in my project:**

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

BS' collapse is part of its JavaScript library, so you need to load that as well:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

With Bootstrap 5, you need to use `data-bs-target` and `data-bs-toggle` instead of `data-target` and `data-toggle`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse open" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Test text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Test text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Test text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So by means besides Bootstrap.min.js i need to additionally add this bundle ?

Comment: @Arie Yes. [But as their official docs state](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/), you don't need jQuery for BS5, so unless you're using jQuery for something else, you can scrap that altogether.